# Dell 6248 Stacking - Cross Connect Does not work

Tags: dell-powerconnect

We have 2 Dell 6248P switches which are stacked, Its all working fine, But the strange thing is that The stacking modules are not cross connected they are connected to the ports inline to each other

Port 1 (Switch 1) --> Port 1( Switch 2)
Port 2 (Switch 1) --> Port 2 (Switch 2)

Whereas it should be

Port 1 (Switch 1) --> Port 2 (Switch 2) , When i did this the whole network went down. None of the switches were accessible. The rest of the configuration was the exact same as defined on the configuration manual

Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you didn't give the stacking protocols enough time to detect and reconverge.

Crossing the cables is not required, but becomes easier to manage as you expand past just two switches. The important part is that the cables form a ring so that if one link is broken traffic can flow the other direction.

If this really just bothers you and you want to fix it, I would plan to power off switch #2 (after backing up and saving your configuration). Then fix the cabling, and power it back on. It should detect the stacking configuration on boot and still be known as switch #2 and just come back online as it was.

Comment: Thanks Spaceman for your response, its highly unlikely that we might go beyond 2 switches as there is ample space left Thanks for your reply. I just have one more question though, We are trying to connect one of the 6248 switches via the combo port to a Powerconnect 8132F SPF+, The links are not even coming up, Ive tried with many cables, looks like it does give me the option on the web UI to switch between the modes, Please do apologize my ignorance as I have mainly worked on cisco

Comment: Hard to say... you're using the SFP ports and transceivers? Are you sure your SFP transceivers and the cable you are using are all the same kind? ie... SFP Copper transceivers with Cat5e/6 in between or SFP+ 10Gb multi-mode fiber modules with multi-mode fiber cables in between? Past that, its proper configuration. Are you using VLANs?

Comment: Ok, I did a bit of snooping around about the hardware, It looks like the 6248's support only SFP whereas the 8132F is SPF+, I'm guessing that they will be backward compatible and work at the speed of SPF, but the transceivers are SPF+ on both ends. Would SPF + transceivers be compatible with the 6248 combo ports ?